# What is creating these files with a jmconfig extension?

Tags: visual-studio

I've got multiple Visual Studio projects and solutions that have a .jmconfig file in the root directory for the project or the solution.  I only noticed that the file shows up when checking my project into source control and it tells me that the .jmconfig is new.

Here is a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><DontShowAgainInSolution>false</DontShowAgainInSolution></Configuration>
```

Comment: What plugins you have installed?

Answer (score 3):

This is JustMock trying to save some settings so that you don't get reminded to upgrade all the time.